# Not able to obtain struct after passing in struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am encountering an error within the function `query`. It is not returning the results.
The function `generate` initializes the results. It is called by the function `query`.

// define structure

```
#define MAX 50

typedef struct {
    char I[50];
    char name[10];
} object;


typedef struct {
    int num_items;
    object items[MAX];
} arg_t;
```

// function generate

```
void generate (object *q) {
    // initialize
    object objectArray[] = {
        {
        .I = "1",
        .name = "John"
        }, // item 1
        {
        .I = "2",
        .name = "Jane"
        }, // item 2
    };

    q = malloc(sizeof(arg_t));

    q->num_items = 2;
    printf("There are %d of elements in the record.\n", q->num_items);
    memcpy(q->items, object, sizeof(object) * q->num_items);

    int i =0;

    for (i=0; i < q->num_items ;i++) {
        printf("option: %s \n", q->items[i].I);
        printf("option: %s \n", q->items[i].name);
    }
    printf("Leaving Generate()\n");
}
```

// function query

```
void query () {
    arg_t qHolder;
    arg_t *q = &qHolder;    // give the pointer an address
    q = malloc(sizeof(arg_t));

    generate (q);
    printf("There are %d of elements in the record.\n", qHolder.num_items); // <b> This line is wrong. It is giving 0 instead of 2. </b>
// There is no compiler error. It just does not print when it runs after the follwing line
    int i =0;

    for (i=0; i < q->num_items;i++) {
        printf("option: %s \n", qHolder.items[i].I);
        printf("option: %s \n", qHolder.items[i].name);
    }
    printf("Leaving Query()\n");
}
```

in main()

```
    query ();
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are asking about the compiler errors you're getting? In the future, please always provide the complete and unedited error log with the question, as that helps us when answering the actual question you have instead of unrelated things.

Comment: There is no compiler error. It just does not print when it runs after the line:
// the following will not work either

Comment: You *should* get compiler errors, as first you call `generate` with a pointer to `arg_t` when the functions wants a pointer to `object`. Then you should get errors inside `generate` as there `q` is a pointer to `object`, and does not have members such as `items` or `num_items`.

Comment: My compiler is not giving any error. It prints :
**
There are 2 of elements in the record.
option: 1
option: John 
option: 2
option: Jane 

Leaving Generate()
There are 0 of elements in the record.
option:  
option:  
option:  
option:  
Leaving Query()

**

Comment: Then the code in the question is not your actual code.

Comment: In the instance that I have to passed from 1 memory area to the next, won't I require the malloc? Say, the call functions are on 2 devices.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47388/discussion-between-babbit-and-joachim-pileborg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `generate()` function takes a `object *q` argument, but the first thing it does is overwrite the pointer's value by assigning the result of `malloc()` to it. Don't do that, there's no need to allocate new memory since the caller is telling you where to store the `object`.

Here's a fixed version:

```
void generate (object *q) {
    // initialize
    const object objectArray[] = {
        {
        .I = "1",
        .name = "John"
        }, // item 1
        {
        .I = "2",
        .name = "Jane"
        }, // item 2
    };

    q->num_items = sizeof objectArray / sizeof *objectArray;
    printf("There are %d of elements in the record.\n", q->num_items);
    memcpy(q->items, objectArray, sizeof objectArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < q->num_items; ++i) {
        printf("option: %s\n", q->items[i].I);
        printf("option: %s\n", q->items[i].name);
    }
    printf("Leaving generate()\n");
}
```

Then in `query()`, you're once again overwriting a pointer by doing a call to `malloc()`. I think you need to read up on the basics a bit.

Here's a fixed version:

```
void query (void) {
    arg_t qHolder;

    generate (&qHolder);
    printf("There are %d of elements in the record.\n", qHolder.num_items);
    for (int i = 0; i < q->num_items; ++i) {
        printf("option: %s \n", Holder.items[i].I);
        printf("option: %s \n", qHolder.items[i].name);
    }
    printf("Leaving query()\n");
}
```

Comment: It's still not returning the value.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a beginners mistake in your `generate` function. You have to remember that in C all arguments are passed by value, meaning their values are copied to the local variables inside the function. That means that when you assign to `q` inside the `generate` function you only assign the the local copy. The argument you pass when calling the `generate` function will not be modified.

Besides, you need to check your design, because in `query` you first make `q` point to `&qHolder`, then you *overwrite* the pointer with your call to `malloc`, **and** you call `malloc` again inside `generate`. So you set the pointer three times, when only one of these is enough.

And I wonder how this compiles without the compiler shouting at you, as `q` is *not* an `object` structure.

Comment: @Babbit Simply remove the `malloc` calls, they are overwriting your original pointer and gives you memory leaks.

Comment: In the instance that I have to passed from 1 memory area to the next, won't I require the malloc? Say, the call functions are on 2 devices.